# qTip 2: trigger hide before delayed show?

Tags: delay, show-hide, qtip2

I'm having an annoying little interaction issue with qTip 2. A button on my page has a tip attached to it, set to appear on `mouseover` after a `500ms` delay and disappear immediately on `mouseout`.

When the button is clicked, the whole view changes and that particular button disappears, so I force the tip to hide immediately (otherwise, it hangs around until the user moves their mouse, even though the button that triggered it is no longer visible).

The problem is that the immediate `hide` event doesn't seem to cancel the delayed `show` event if it happens to occur first. In other words, if the user points at the button and clicks it in less than `500ms`, the `hide` event triggers (doing nothing) and *then* the `show` event triggers at `500ms`, causing the tooltip to display even thought the button is no longer there (and in the wrong position to boot, since it can't position itself correctly without the button being visible).

Is there a way when I trigger the `hide` event to tell it to just stop there and not perform any other events?

Comment: you can use the show or render event to check if the button visible , and if not than dont show it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this (@Daniel, your answer was close so I'll upvote you too):

```
events: {
    show: function(event, api) {
        if ($("#mybutton").is(':hidden')) {
            try { event.preventDefault(); } catch(e) {}
        }
    }
};
```

This is the method that [qTip's documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/events/#stop) recommends.

Answer (score 1):

*Not Tested*

You can use the show event to check if the button visible , and if not than don't show it....

Something like this:

```
 events: {
       show: function(event, api) {
           var target = event.originalEvent.target;
           if($("#idOfButton").length === 0 ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              //or try this (commednt the above and uncomment the code below)
              //clearTimeout(api.timers.custom);  
           }
       }
}
```